# Is there a way to use ESP NOW protocol using lua?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

i'm working on a project using esp8266 nodemcu board, and found right at the beginning that there is an IDE for this board called ESPlorer IDE which uses Lua code, so i've using https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io as my go to, but now i want to implement the esp now protocol on my project but i can't since there is no documentation for it's usage on lua, so my question is. Is there a way to use ESP NOW protocol using lua?
or do i have to use another IDE and start all over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ESPNow protocol isn't supported by the NodeMCU firmware by default; [there's an issue requesting support](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/2924) from September 2019.

If you're adept in C, you could maybe be the hero to implement that, but otherwise... no, unfortunately you can't use ESPNow with NodeMCU/Lua.

Comment: I was suspecting that, how dissappointing, either way thank you for answering